# How to use the OFFSET function in Rows() function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a function that will hide certain rows based on what drop down option you've selected. I have to reuse this code multiple times in the worksheet so I dont want it to be cell dependent, and instead use the OFFSET function.

This is what I have written

```
Tcell = Range("D3")

If Tcell = "example 1" Then 
    Rows("4:19").Hidden = False
    Rows("12:19").Hidden = True
ElseIf Tcell = "example 2" Then
    Rows("4:19").Hidden = False
    Rows("10:19").Hidden = True
ElseIf Tcell = "example 3" Then
    Rows("4:19").Hidden = False
    Rows("16:19").Hidden = True
End If
```

I tried using something like this below, but it had an type 13 match error. Thank you for your help!

```
 If Tcell = "example 1" Then 
    Rows("Tcell.Offset(1):Tcell.Offset(16)").Hidden = False
    Rows("Tcell.Offset(1):Tcell.Offset(16)").Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) is a property of a `Range` object and does not belong within parentheses. Neither does `Tcell`.

First change `Tcell` to be a `Range` and `Set` it.

Then you can use [`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) and [`Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) here:

```
Dim Tcell As Range
Set Tcell = ActiveSheet.Range("D3")

If Tcell.Value = "example 1" then
    ActiveSheet.Rows(Tcell.Row).Offset(1).Resize(16).Hidden = False 
    ActiveSheet.Rows(Tcell.Row).Offset(9).Resize(8).Hidden = True

' and similarly for the other cases

End If
```

Comment: You'll need to Dim Tcell as a range I think and then set it using "set Tcell = Range("D3")"

Comment: @Amiga500 - good point. I overlooked the `Tcell = Range("D3")` since it was outside the code block in the question. Edited to fix that and the answer.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you for your help. I was wondering where the 9 and 8 come from in the second line ? Sorry, I just started using vba a couple weeks ago.

Comment: That's just simple math. If your starting cell is in row 3 and you want to get to row 12, you offset 9 rows. Then `Rows("12:19")` contains 8 rows.